# Definitive Way(s) Of Knowing That One Has Bought The Revised Model Of The Nexus 5?

Tags: nexus-5

After complaints by many about the build quality of the Nexus 5, Google has apparently made certain hardware changes and released a revised version of its latest flagship handset in the last couple of days.

How can one ensure that they have the latest model of the Nexus 5 (or is it a given or matter of trust, that the Google Play Store and retailers will supply the latest). ?

Comment: All I've seen (so far) is a [physical comparison](http://www.cultofandroid.com/47687/google-revises-nexus-5-design-fix-early-issues/) of the two models, more-or-less requiring you to have both models in hand to compare. Not very useful when you're shopping. I've seen no mention of a modified model number or anything like that. You might just need to roll the dice.

Comment: @Krampus I understand what you are saying, but I haven't physically handled "the original", so wouldn't know.

Comment: You can look at the photos, surely, then check the model you get and see if, for example, you have the old or new style holes at the bottom.  On the other hand, if you're not sure but you don't have a problem with quiet sound levels or protruding SIM trays then you don't have a problem anyway.

Comment: @Poldie Your second sentence doesn't really make a whole lot of sense. If they have produced a revised model, that has supposedly rectified issues, why on Earth would I be content with quiet sound levels and protruding SIM trays ? The whole point is to BE SURE !!

Comment: @Poldie Surely there is definitive way ie by Batch/IMEI/Serial Number that identifies the revised model.

Comment: Many, many people are apparently happy with the first generation phones, therefore either not all phones are affected, or some people might not have any problem with low volumes/protruding SIM trays if they are affected. I'm suggesting the same might be true for whatever phone you receive.  Clearly if the phone level is too quiet for you then it's not good, so at that point you'd return it.

Comment: @Poldie Yes I totally agree with you. Hopefully many of the issues that plagued a minority of people in the first version have now hopefully been rectified in the revised version. I just wanted to make sure that at this point in time, if someone were to purchase a Nexus 5 they are getting the latest version rather than being given "old stock" by whichever retailer.

Comment: @Krampus XDA thread about serial numbers which people claim identifies the new from the old version http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48682988&postcount=206

Comment: @AlE. This article may clear up any confusion http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2597276

Comment: @AlE. Another way to look at it, if you buy the newly released Red version of the Nexus 5, then you will definitely have the latest model :)